# The aria-labelledby attribute must point to IDs of elements in the same document. These IDs weren't found: mat-expansion-panel-header-1

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I have code like this :

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]=true class="my-card-expansion-panel">
 <br/>
 Testdata1
 <br/>
 Testdata2
 <br/>
 Testdata3
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

but I am getting below accessibility error, HTML5 WCAG 2.1 A 1.3.1 Section 508 (2017) A 1.3.1 ARIA 1.2

> The aria-labelledby attribute must point to IDs of elements in the same document.
> These IDs weren't found: mat-expansion-panel-header-1

How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which tool/application is giving this error?